# Sorting linked list by sorting the actual nodes and not just by swapping node values

Tags: c, sorting

I want to sort my linked list so that the nodes are arranged in the sorted order. I have looked up several algorithms, but they all swap the data values and not the actual node itself. Does anyone know where I can find some code on how to swap the nodes themselves and not just the values?

Comment: A linked list is NOT an array, it is NOT sequential in memory at all. The only *links* between the nodes are simple pointers that point to the next node in memory that daisy-chain the collection of nodes together into the list. The normal way to sort a list is by simply rewiring the pointers to point to the nodes in order. If an ordered-list is your goal, then an insert *in order* is called for. Whether you are rewiring pointers or swapping values of the nodes, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the traditional and fastest way to merge sort a linked list. It's a bottom up style merge sort that uses an array of pointers to nodes to hold intermediate lists, where array[i] is either null or points to a list with 2 to the power i nodes. Nodes from the original list are merged into the array, then the lists in the array are merged to form a single sorted list. HP / Microsoft C++ STL std::list::sort uses the same algorithm.

```
/* prototype */
NODE * MergeLists(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2);

/* sort list using array of pointers to first nodes of list   */
/* aList[i] = NULL or ptr to list with 2 to the power i nodes */

#define NUMLISTS 32                 /* size of array */
NODE * SortList(NODE *pList)
{
NODE * aList[NUMLISTS];             /* array of lists */
NODE * pNode;
NODE * pNext;
int i;
    if(pList == NULL)               /* check for empty list */
        return NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)   /* zero array */
        aList[i] = NULL;
    pNode = pList;                  /* merge nodes into array */
    while(pNode != NULL){
        pNext = pNode->next;
        pNode->next = NULL;
        for(i = 0; (i < NUMLISTS) && (aList[i] != NULL); i++){
            pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
            aList[i] = NULL;
        }
        if(i == NUMLISTS)           /* don't go past end of array */
            i--;
        aList[i] = pNode;
        pNode = pNext;
    }
    pNode = NULL;                   /* merge array into one list */
    for(i = 0; i < NUMLISTS; i++)
        pNode = MergeLists(aList[i], pNode);
    return pNode;
}

/* mergelists -  compare uses src2 < src1           */
/* instead of src1 <= src2 to be similar to C++ STL */

NODE * MergeLists(NODE *pSrc1, NODE *pSrc2)
{
NODE *pDst = NULL;                  /* destination head ptr */
NODE **ppDst = &pDst;               /* ptr to head or prev->next */
    if(pSrc1 == NULL)
        return pSrc2;
    if(pSrc2 == NULL)
        return pSrc1;
    while(1){
        if(pSrc2->data < pSrc1->data){  /* if src2 < src1 */
            *ppDst = pSrc2;
            pSrc2 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc2->next));
            if(pSrc2 == NULL){
                *ppDst = pSrc1;
                break;
            }
        } else {                        /* src1 <= src2 */
            *ppDst = pSrc1;
            pSrc1 = *(ppDst = &(pSrc1->next));
            if(pSrc1 == NULL){
                *ppDst = pSrc2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pDst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this :
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/

It shows how to sort the linked list using merge sort and that too by changing pointers.

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered as good because it will become invalid if what is linked vanishes. Please include the important points in your answer.

Comment: The geeks for geeks example is inefficient, using  a top down array oriented approach on a list which requires repeated scanning of sub-lists to split them in half. I posted an answer with the traditional bottom up approach using an array of pointers to nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than swapping the content, change the pointer/"next_item" variables to point to the correct node for the new order.